# Semantic does not reload c-preprocessor symbols from file

Tags: semantic-mode

`semantic` allows specification of C-preprocessor keywords using the variable `semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file`, which is a list of C/C++ files that contain preprocessor macros. How do I get `semantic` to reload these files after changing one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`semantic` uses the variable `semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-map` to store the C preprocessor keywords used by its C lexer. The function `semantic-c-reset-preprocessor-symbol-map` reconstructs this table using all the various input methods. So, on changing a file listed in `semantic-lex-c-preprocessor-symbol-file`, run `(semantic-c-reset-preprocessor-symbol-map)` to load these changes into `semantic`s environment.